# Need a software where I write in markdown and it gets published in my domain name hosted on github?

Tags: blog

I want a static site generator where I need to do minimal customizations. I want to edit the menus all using GUI instead of doing them via code or configuration files. Any guidance? Also I want to use a CMS instead of tinkering the code everytime I write.

Comment: This screams GitHub pages: https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

Once you install it in your site, you need to just duplicate your post and write everything through markdown.

Also there are tons of themes to customize the looks. Best of all it runs well in GitHub pages. Just commit and push your changes and the post is live.

Comment: I didn't find good course to get started with jekyll and deploy a blog. Sorry I am not tech savvy.

Comment: Download and install Ruby and the Devkit from rubyinstaller.org
Click the checkbox to run ridk install on the final screen.
In the command window that appears, choose option 3 to install MSYS2 and the MINGW development toolchain
Open an new command window and install Jekyll on Windows with the following command:
`gem install jekyll bundler`
Create a new blog with the `jekyll new myblog`
From the myblog folder created in the previous step issue the following command
cd myblog
bundle exec jekyll serve
Open `http://localhost:4000` and view your Jekyll blog.

Comment: This comment is supposing that you are using windows. If you have other operating system, search for your specific operating system instructions. This is something you will deal with just the first time. Writing blog posts will be a breeze once the setup is done.